# Spring Batch optional or conditional Multithreading

Tags: multithreading, spring-batch

I am implementing a Spring Batch using JdbcPagingItemReader and JdbcBatchItemWriter. I have used TaskExecutor to achieve multi-threading using setConcurrencyLimit. But I may not have huge data everytime, so can I achieve multithreading as needed? Like turning it on and off using a parameter?

Answer (score 2):

You can add SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor to the step config to make it Multi-threaded. Below is a sample snippet of the Step config where you can control adding TaskExecutor on a conditional basis,

```
    @Bean
    public Step testStepConfig() {

       boolean multiThreadingRequired = false; // It can be picked from the external config

       AbstractTaskletStepBuilder<SimpleStepBuilder<String, Data>> stepConfig = stepBuilderFactory
            .get("testStep").<String, Data>chunk(10)
            .reader(reader()).processor(processor()).writer(writer())
            .faultTolerant().retryLimit(3)
            .listener(testStepListener());

       if (multiThreadingRequired) {
           stepConfig.taskExecutor(taskExecutor());
       }

       return stepConfig.build();
   }


   @Bean
   public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
       SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();
       taskExecutor.setConcurrencyLimit(deleteTenantsMaxThreads);
       return taskExecutor;
   }
```

Comment: Thank You. I have used ApplicationArguments and passed them through command line arguments. This approach works too.

Comment: @ThinkCode That's great :)